# Using common WPF styles in UserControl Library project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am developing a WPF project, which has own user control library. There I have to make a common style for all DataGrids ScrollBars. How can I add such style as a resource within that project, and apply it globally in it?

In WPF application, I can use App.xaml to accomplish that. But I have no idea how to do that in Control Library.

Please help (:

Comment: See this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115783/global-static-resources-in-a-wpf-class-library

Answer (score 0):

`UserControls` are not contained in one `App.xaml` so there is no way of achieving this the way WPF app does. But if you want this `Style` to be applied to every `DataGrid ScrollBar` you need to define `Style` that applies to every `DataGrid` i.e.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:DataGrid}" TargetType="local:DataGrid">
```

and then inside of the style target the `Scrollbar` as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
```

when defined in your `App.xaml` it will target every DataGrid's ScrollBar.
You need to define this style in your `App.xaml` and when you use your `UC` it will be applied to them unconditionally.
**Note**
If you want to add the Stye to existing one you need to add `BasedOn:{StaticResource nameOfYourStyle}`.
HTH
Example based on MSDN [ScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) example Styles.